# Have the Borg nanoprobes been copied by the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, borg

The "Borg nanoprobe" seems to be the Borg's most powerful weapon. The Federation and others obviously have similar technology but have they ever copied, developed or controlled Borg nanoprobe tech? They've had plenty of opportunities to acquire samples in order to back-engineer the technology.

Comment: They have controlled the tech at least twice, in *Scorpion* 1 & 2 and again in *In the Flesh.*

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Nanoprobe

Comment: @Xantec That's Voyager? I must admit I've seen less that half of the Voyager episodes but I'm not sure about considering Voyager,  'Federation' though.

Comment: @Morgan Yes, those are Voyager episodes. Since they did return to Earth at the end of series (and were in frequent communication before then) it should be safe to consider them "Federation".

Comment: @Morgan: “I'm not sure about considering Voyager, 'Federation' though” — what are they then, Klingon?

Comment: @Xantec I agree with you. You should write your comment up as an answer. It's been a while, but episodes "Prey" and "Warhead" may also be examples of Voyager using nanoprobes.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You funny man Dr. Jones, I kill you last.

Comment: @rosesunhill feel free to run with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Xantec noted and Richard provided a link in the comments above, Voyager used modified Borg several times:

> In 2374, The Doctor was able to modify nanoprobes as an offensive weapon against Species 8472. He reprogrammed them to mimic the alien cells' electrochemical signatures, so that they could evade detection by Species 8472's immune system while continuing to assimilate. These nanoprobes could be delivered inside a photon torpedo or along a phaser beam. (VOY: "Scorpion", "Scorpion, Part II", "Prey")
>
> Nanoprobes could also be modified to attack specific cells which contained a virus or some other disease and so help the patient recover. In 2375, Seven of Nine encoded some of her nanoprobes to assimilate the synthehol molecules in Kadi Ambassador Tomin's bloodstream, allowing him to recover from his intoxication in time to return to his people. (VOY: "Someone to Watch Over Me")
>
> Since bio-neural circuitry is organic in nature, nanoprobes could also be used to influence or disable this type of circuitry. (VOY: "Warhead")

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nanoprobe

Comment: I would have thought the Federation or other major power would have focused their efforts to crack this weapon. Apparently only a single Federation ship on the edge of nowhere thought of this.

Comment: Maybe Janeway is the Mother of Invention? Ouch.

Answer (score 2):

They have... on several occasions in Voyager.

- They used Seven-of-Nine's nanoprobes to revive Neelix when he was killed by a protomatter cloud discharge in [VOY: Mortal Coil](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mortal_Coil_(episode))
- They again used her nanoprobes to 'arrest' the alcohol particles and make an alien ambassador... well, sober in [VOY: Someone To Watch Over Me](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Someone_to_Watch_Over_Me_(episode))
- Another occasions saw the use of Seven's nanoprobes to bypass/repair Iko's edema in the brain (Which also seemed to have activated his conscience) in [VOY: Repentance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Repentance_(episode))

Apart from that, her nanoprobes were also sampled and replicated on several occasions to be used in effective manner against species 8472 in [VOY: Scorpion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion_(episode))

Also, the Federation DID develop their own nanites in medicine for surgeries, etc in TNG... however, this is not frequently seen (otherwise, the Doctor in Voyager would not have resorted that often to using Borg nanoprobes).

Then again, none of the show's doctors (either the EMH or Bashir) were seen using stem-cells to regenerate lost limbs in people (Nog's leg for example) or rejuvenate the body to reverse ageing which is already largely possible in real life. Trek seemed to have no problem with prosthetic limbs, etc. but no use of actual stem-cells.

---

I'd imagine that when it comes to program-ability in regards to medical aspects, Federation nanites and Borg nanoprobes are pretty similar if not downright the same. Actually it would be easier and far less dangerous for the Federation to use its own medical nanites than Borg tech which could technically assimilate a person if something goes wrong.

Granted, Borg technology seems to be more adaptive, but the underlying basis of their technology is nanotechnology... and the Federation developed its own version before meeting the Borg... so there's no reason they couldn't use their own nanites and possibly use some of their experiences with Borg nanoprobes to enhance function of their own nanites (not just in medical aspects, but others as well).

> **CRUSHER:** *Nanites. Tiny machines built from the atom up. Designed to have exposure only to the inside of nucleii during cellular surgeries. Until then, they are kept tightly confined in a non-functioning state.*
>
> **DATA:** *These are not ordinary nanites.*
>
> **CRUSHER:** *No, they have evolved.*
>
> **STUBBS:** *Evolved? How does a machine evolve?*
>
> **WESLEY:** *It's true. I am responsible for this. I allowed two of the nanites to interact for a school project. I wanted to increase their capabilities. And they escaped.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Evolution](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Evolution_(episode))</sup></sub>

The Federation seems to be using their own developed nanites in cellular surgery, however, prior to Wesley allowing them to interact, they have been using them in a fairly limited fashion. Also, Beverly Crusher DID suggest introducing a destructive breed of nanites into the Collective at one point.

However, I find it very unusual (not to mention implausible) that the Federation wouldn't have the technical ability to program the nanites to interact with each other inside human body or outside of it and perform specific tasks without 'spontaneous evolution' occurring.

And before someone says that this might be akin to keeping nanites in a state that makes them not self aware... one could argue the same thing about Holodecks too, because they are also capable of creating fully self-aware AI for example, but that still doesn't prevent the crew from using the holodecks for training, relaxation, recreation, etc.

Comment: You've described the events of several episodes without explaining which episodes they happened in. Adding in links would take this answer from fair to good.

Comment: Federation and Borg nanites are similar? [VOY: Inside Man](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/705.htm) would suggest that the Borg's nanoprobes are *dramatically more advanced* than Federation tech; "***BARCLAY**: Oh, nanoprobes aren't just for assimilating. They can reanimate necrotic tissue, slow down the aging process. They'd be priceless for the Ferengi."*

Comment: Nanites are microscopic machines that conduct specific tasks after being programmed to do so.
Borg nanoprobes are no different... but I DID mention that they might be more adaptive (in this respect, they might have been the only viable way to use against species 8472).

In restrospect, we hadn't seen much of the Federation nanite technology even in medicine after Crusher mentioned it... as if it was just forgotten (like most other things the Federation developed before it just disappeared).

Wesley Crusher also allowed 2 nanites to interact, which ended up in creation of a lifeform

Comment: Wesley's Nanites had access to the a vast supply of computer core material before they became intelligent.

Comment: Wesley's nanites are Federation based technology... and they achieved in a minuscule timeframe what Borg nanotech did not.

Arguably, if wesley's Nanites could do that, that suggests highly adaptive programming (which had to have been present BEFORE Wesley allowed them to interact).

Problem is, we just never see the Federation using nanites in any significat capacity... nor stem-cells, or anything else that would be extremely useful.

Comment: As I said, this answer is probably the closest I've seen from you to being the standard I'd upvote. If you add in episode links and provide some quotes to back up your assertions, I'm sure you'll find that this gets some love.

Comment: My point was that regardless of having access to a vast supply of computer core material, the Nanites used that raw material to accomplish something extremely powerful.

If programmed to reverse ageing, repair cell damage, or whatever else, they would utilize the raw material inside the human(oid) body to do pretty much that (Without killing the host obviously - as you'd want the nanites to help repair and maintain existing cells, encourage production of new stem-cells for example, and utilize excess fat and waste from say food consumption as raw materials).

Comment: Episode 1, Season 3 of TNG labeled 'Evolution'.

Comment: @Dek regarding us rarely seeing advanced technology based on modern science being used (nanites, stem-cells, etc), with the amount of hand-wavium and technobable throughout the shows and movies, it's possible we _have_ seen it used, but under a different name.

Comment: I agree its possible... but especially in regards to say nanites that are very similar (if not identical) to Borg nanoprobes in underlying basic technology, you would think the Federation would be jumping on the chance to using it in a similar manner like the Borg for hull repairs, maintenance, upgrades, etc.

Mind you, the writers never had the technical skill to write it into the show properly, because the Trek Federation should have probably been WAY beyond even that...